Why does my data drift from the nernst equation at low values of Q?
I saw a similar question from last year but there were no answers and I was facing the same problem.
I designed an experiment for a nickel-nickel concentration cell where the cathode is kept at 1M and the anode concentration was decreased by a factor of 10 each time (0.1M, 0.01M, 0.001M, 0.0001M, 0.00001M). My experimental values are very close to theoretical at high values of Q (0.1) but at lower concentrations (Q=0.00001) they drift above theoretical.
I've read about the Debye-Huckel theory and how molarity can't be used to give an accurate value of Q at concentration >0.1M but then since the anode was kept at 1M it doesn't quite explain the drift at lower Q. And my error bars for average uncertainty don't completely explain this trend either.

Using such low concentrations is not good idea, bringing kinetic issues and not well defined side reactions or adsorption.

Provide more details. are there other substances then water and a nickel salt? // Consider 10 ppm is about 0.6 mg/L and that there could be significant changes of the value (hydrolysis, dissolving the electrode, adsoption on glass surface....)

@Poutnik What are these kinetic issues specifically? I'm not too experienced with this side of chemistry. There is a 1M KCl salt bridge but not too sure how this changes the percentage error for lower concentrations since it's kept constant throughout.

If the nickel concentration is less than $0.001$ M, the anode will tend to increase the concentration of $\ce{Ni^{2+}}$ around the anode simply as the cell is working. So in the vicinity of the anode the nickel ionic concentration becomes a bit higher than in solution when the cell is working. Nernst's law cannot be applied with the concentration in the solution, taken far from the electrode.
